# Delete selected row in listview in android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, binding

I have a listview with custom row having a textview and a clickable image for deleting the row. Listview gets the data from sqlite database. I have successfully loaded the data from the database into the listview. What I want is to delete that row from the database when delete button is pressed. I know this requires binding onclick event handler to the delete button and getting the object or sqlite data bound with the row. How can I get the sqlite data bound with the row on which the user clicked the delete button?
Here is my adapter to the listview

```
public class CommentAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Comment> {

// private objects
private List<Comment> mListComment;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;

public CommentAdapter(Context c,int textViewResourceId, List<Comment> list) {
    super(c, textViewResourceId, list);
    mListComment = list;
    // create layout inflater
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mListComment.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // get view reference
    View view = convertView;
    // if null
    if(view == null) {
        // inflate new layout
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.comment_row, null);
        // create a holder
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        // find controls
        holder.txtComment = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtComment);
        holder.btnDelete = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
        // set data structure to view
        view.setTag(holder);
    }

    Comment cmt = mListComment.get(position);
    // if not null
    if(cmt != null) {
        // query data structure
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
        // set data to display
        holder.txtComment.setText(cmt.getComment());
        holder.btnDelete.setClickable(true);
        holder.btnDelete.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_delete);

    }

    // return view
    return view;
}

/*
 * @class ViewHolder
 * to hold data structure on view with comment info
 */
static class ViewHolder {
    private TextView txtComment;
    private ImageView btnDelete;

}
}
```

Here is my CommentsDataSource class

```
public class CommentsDataSource {
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
private String[] allColumns = { DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ID, DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_COMMENT };

public CommentsDataSource(Context context) {
    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

public void open() throws SQLException {
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void close() {
    dbHelper.close();
}

public Comment createComment(String comment) {
    //insert into databasae
    return newComment;
}

private Comment cursorToComment(Cursor cursor) {
    //convert cursor to comment
    return comment;
}

public void deleteComment(Comment comment) {
    //delete row from datbase
}


public List<Comment> getAllComments() {
    //get all rows
    return comments;
}

}
```

Comment: You need a cursor adapter which binds to your database. Changes to your database are reflected in your cursor adapter. Deleting or inserting into the database would then reflect in your list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mobify your getView method as below:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // get view reference
    View view = convertView;
    // if null
    if(view == null) {
        // inflate new layout
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.comment_row, null);
        // create a holder
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        // find controls
        holder.txtComment = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtComment);
        holder.btnDelete = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
        // set data structure to view
        view.setTag(holder);
    }

    final Comment cmt = mListComment.get(position);
    // if not null
    if(cmt != null) {
        // query data structure
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
        // set data to display
        holder.txtComment.setText(cmt.getComment());
        holder.btnDelete.setClickable(true);
        holder.btnDelete.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_delete);
        holder.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
               public void onClick(View view)
               {
                     commentsDataSource.deleteComment(cmt);
                     //Requery DB to get Updated results
                     notifyDataSetChanged();
               }
        })

    }

    // return view
    return view;
}
```

Comment: inside the onclick event handler, when i refer to cmt object i get error message as cannot refer to a non-final variable cmt inside an inner class defined in different method. could u plz help

Comment: @just declare your `Comment cmt ` in your class  not in `getView` method.

Comment: actually its not needed, just declareing it as final should work

Comment: i declared cmt as class variable and modified onclick handler as  System.out.println(cmt.getId()+cmt.getComment()); now when i clicked on each row delete button i get only the last row value as seen in my log

Comment: no need for decalring it as class variable, see my comment above, it would delete your last element of list only.

Comment: yes it would just get me the last row values, how can i get the values of selected row

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your `onlistitemclicklistener` in your extended `ListActivity`. It would be something like this.

```
@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        ViewHolder item = (ViewHolder ) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        Toast.makeText(this, item.txtComment  + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Now, make your handler to delete the selected row. You've have `listview`, `current view` and the `indexed id`. Hope, it will works

Answer (score 0):

write a listener for button click and in the onClick() method, use this code:

```
@Override
protected void onClick(View view){
    view.getParent().setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

I hope this will work for you.
Alternately, as I don't have time to check the above code, if that doesn't work, in the `getView()` method, you can store the `view` and the button into two separate `ArrayList`, then get the index of button in the `onClick()`, from button `ArrayList`, and set the visibility of same index in the view `ArrayList` as `GONE`. This method is kinda dirty one, so I prefer the above method.

Answer (score -1):

```
Listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { 
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List.remove(position);   
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Comment: Maybe this is helpful to answer the question, you need to explain how to use your solution and why this solves the issue